# Recommendations for an intro level virology textbook?

Tags: virology, virus, book-recommendation, retrovirus

I'm a college sophomore, and I was just accepted into a research lab that works with retroviruses. Since I haven't taken any classes on the topic yet, does anyone have recommendations for good, intro-level virology textbooks I could work through to learn some background information?

Comment: You can ask the head of the lab or your supervisor, they might have targeted ideas for your research.

Comment: Have you taken any molecular biology or biochemistry? They seem like a prereq to virology.

Comment: Have a look at the [tag wiki](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/book-recommendation/info) on [tag:book-recommendation]. You should provide more details in your question, otherwise it seems broad and tends to generate opinion-based answers.

Comment: http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP001462.html This book is good enough to guide through the course.

Comment: *Understanding Viruses*, 2nd ED by Shors is the current recommended text at my university for the undergraduate virology course. If you're interested in the area, as suggested in the comments, I'd recommend some reading in cell and molecular biology to really get a sense of the host dynamics. Alberts' *Molecular Biology of the Cell,* and Watson's *Molecular Biology of the Gene* are standard core texts. Really, though, the only prereq to our virology course is the upper-level microbiology course.